# Customize view with ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

I cant figure out how to get the whole area of Ireland, see code:

```
library(ggmap)
map <- get_map(location = 'Ireland', zoom = 7, maptype = "terrain", force = TRUE)
```

See how it is shifted up north... 
Thanks.

Comment: what about manually adjusting `get_map(location = c(lon = ..., lat = ...)` to get the center where you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following using `ggmap()` and `ggplot()`

In `ggmap`there is a function  `get_map()` that creates a data frame with relevant geographical information for plotting a map. For your case it would be something like this

```
ireland = map_data("world", region = "ireland")
```

Then you just need to use `geom_polygon()`and it should work.

```
map = ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = ireland, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
+   coord_fixed(1.5)
```

The result it yields is: [image]

Comment: thanks, not exactly what I was looking for but it would work. I am trying to add argument  `col` but it is not working. any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure that I am understanding what you mean by `col`. If you wanted colour blue for example, you may use `fill`. `ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = ireland, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "blue") + 
  coord_fixed(1.5)`

Comment: That works, thanks. Just another questions, since this was not happening with map I got with `get_map` function.Now my data points are a bit of, some points are plotted outside the island which should not happen. Any idea, should I pass some additional argument as a reference for coordinate system?